# Delete Files/Folders under Program Files in Windows 7 / Vista

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-7, windows-vista

We are rewriting our app to make it Windows Vista/7 compliant.  In order to do that, I need to delete all the previous data in the application directory under %PROGRAMFILES%.  This definitely will not work in user mode, and also doesn't appear to work programmatically in admin mode.  I am trying to use the following line of code:

```
File.Delete(filePath);
```

Is there a way to write code to delete files in both user and admin mode?  Going forward we will store all data under the %ALLUSERSPROFILE% directory, but until then I need to write migration code to handle this for the user.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to handle the migration on installation of the update (have the installer do the work)?

Comment: Yes, it would be better to do it that way and that is what I would prefer to do.  However, that would cause serious rework of how we currently distribute our application and is outside the scope of this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to start the application as an administrator in order to get write access to %PROGRAMFILES%. In addition, if UAC is on, you may still get prompted for permission to continue even when running as an administrator.

As C-Pound Guru said in the comment to your question, your update installer (which should be run by an administrator) should also do the cleanup of old files.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\DeleteTest\test.txt"))
    {
        // Use a try block to catch IOExceptions, to 
        // handle the case of the file already being 
        // opened by another process. 
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Public\DeleteTest\test.txt");
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return;
        }
```